# VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [object]

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am using django-haystack and elasticsearch on my Ubuntu server and finding that certain search queries just raise an error page, and I have no idea why this is happening..
Any help appreciated! :)

model.py :

```
class EnActress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    image_urls = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    images = models.TextField(null=True)
    actress_image = models.TextField(null=True)


class EnMovielist(models.Model):
    content_ID = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    release_date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    running_time = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    actress = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image_urls = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    images = models.TextField(null=True)
    image_paths = models.TextField(null=True)
```

search.indexes.py :

```
 class EnActressIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
         text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
         en_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')

         def get_model(self):
             return EnActress
         def index_queryset(self, using=None):
             return self.get_model().objects.all()

 class EnMovielistIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
      text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
      content_ID = indexes.CharField(model_attr='content_ID')
      release_date = indexes.CharField(model_attr='release_date')
      actress = indexes.CharField(model_attr='actress')
      label = indexes.CharField(model_attr='label')

      def get_model(self):
          return EnMovielist

      def index_queryset(self, using=None):
          return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

This is an Error massage in Django

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /search/
Failed lookup for key [actress_image] in 'EnMovielist object'


 Failed lookup for key [%s] in %r
 In template /home/ubuntu/venv/avdict/dmmactress/templates/search/search.html, error at line 122

 112                {% load staticfiles %}
 113                <table class="table table-striped table-hover"                            cellspacing="0" id='result_table'>
 114                    <thead>
 115                        <tr>
 116                            <th>phto</th>
 117                            <th>name</th>
 118                        </tr>
 119                    </thead>
 120                    <tbody>
 121                        <tr class="active">
 122                            {% with   image='enActress/'|add:result.object.actress_image %}
 123                            <td><img src="{% static image %}" class="img-circle" class="img-responsive"  alt="{{result.object.name}}"></td>
 124                            <td>{{ result.object.name }}</td>
 125                            {% endwith %}
 126                        </tr>
 127    
 128                    </tbody>
 129                </table>
 130                {% empty %}
 131                    <p>no results.</p>
 132                {% endfor %}


enactress_text.txt file : 

     {{ object.name}}
     {{ object.actress_image }}

 enmovielist_text.txt file :

     {{ object.content_ID }}
     {{ object.image_paths }}
     {{ object.release_date }}
     {{ object.running_time }}
     {{ object.actress }}
     {{ object.series }}
     {{ object.director }}
     {{ object.label }}
```

Comment: Where does your `result.object` come from? As you can see from the error message, your program tries to access the field `actress_image` in an object of type `EnMovielist`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed lookup for key [actress_image] in 'EnMovielist object'
```

This means you are looking up the `actress_image` value of an `EnMovielist` object.

What you are presumably trying to do requires `result.object` to be an instance of `EnActress`.